# WebService logging a unique id per WebMethod request

Tags: .net, web-services, asynchronous, asmx, webmethod

I'm adding a logging system to a .Net ASMX WebService which is running as a windows service.
The aim is to log each call to a WebMethod under a different request id to be able to identify in the logs all the entries made for a particular request.

To set the scene a little more, each WebMethod creates HttpWebRequest's to communicate with other hosts.

In the first attempts at solving the problem I made use of storing the request id per thread using the following:

- **[ThreadStatic] static int requestId**
- **Thread.GetData** and **Thread.SetData** to store the request id per thread.

However I soon realised that the requests were swapping threads and this was not reliable.

I lastly attempted to use **HttpContext.Current.Items** to store the request id per WebMethod request, however this wasn't entirely reliable as HttpContext.Current.Items could be empty at times.

Investigating further I believe this could be due to the sending of HttpWebRequest's within the WebMethod, my reason for thinking this is due to async calls occuring within the HttpWebRequest which may lose the original HttpContext and therefore it's items.

Comment: How do you have your ASMX service running as a Windows Service? That's not an out of the box feature. OOB, only IIS is supported as a host.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve? Do you want different ID for every request or do you want to use the same ID for each "session"  ?

Comment: John, we have our own http service which creates a HttpListener. A HttpServerWorkerRequest is created for the request which is passed to HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest.

Comment: Maxim, different ID per request. The issue is attempting to obtain an id in our log architecture which is a statically defined class with static log methods. This is why I have been attempting to use HttpContext.Current etc as it can be accessed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to save 'state', even if you succeed this solution won't scale when you'll want to use multiple servers.

You can generate a GUID for each request.

```
Guid.NewGuid()
```

And use it as the ID.

Comment: Yes that makes sense I agree. The issue is not so much generating the request id, which a guid makes perfect sense. The reason I am attempting to store it somewhere is due to writing to the log which is static such as Log.Debug(message). These are throughout the code and I was attempting to try and reduce the need to add the request id as a parameter as the log writes are scattered throughout the code.

Comment: You can generate the GUID in your logging infrastructure.